# Does Android Street View API have usage limits in native android apps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-street-view

I would like to know if there are any usage limits for using the [Google Street View api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/streetview) from Google Play Services 4.4 in native Android aps.

According to https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#usagelimits there are usage limits in using Google Street View Image API's but there are no limits for native apps using Maps APIs, which seem to be contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik as per their official [website](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key) , it hints that

> To access the Google Maps servers with the Maps API, you have to add a Maps API key to your application. The key is free, you can use it with any of your applications that call the Maps API, and it supports an unlimited number of users. You obtain a Maps API key from the Google APIs Console by providing your application's signing certificate and its package name. Add the key to your application by adding an element to your application's AndroidManifest.xml file.

The StreetView map which they added recently is extension of the Google Map in Satellite/Simple mode and same thing should applicable for StreetView also.

Comment: The Street View API is not accessible unless the API_KEY is specified in the AndroidManifest.xml file. This leads me to believe the service has no usage limits per IP. However I'm not sure it hasn't limits on the API key.